# Can't parse JSON from data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm currently trying to parse a JSON from a data attribute but I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

This is my code:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
 let variations = $( "span" ).data( "variations" );

 $( JSON.parse( variations ) ).each( function ( index, variation ) {
  console.log( variation );
 } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-variations='["\ud83d\udc36","\ud83d\udc31"]'></span>
```

I don't get it. I'm printing the JSON in PHP with this function but I'm stuck in my head here:

```
<span data-variations='<?= esc_html( json_encode( $variations ) ) ?>'></span>
```

Comment: So, what's the contents of `variations`?

Comment: When a string starts with '{' or '[', then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse it; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. A string not parseable as a JavaScript value is not converted. -- Looks like jQuery already parses it for you, don't need to `JSON.parse` again.

Comment: @Zeljka well in this case it **is** interpreted (by jQuery) as JSON.

Comment: @Zeljka `["\ud83d\udc36","\ud83d\udc31"]` is a valid JSON.

Comment: @Zeljka: No, that's not what's happening there. It _is_ a valid JSON string, and as such, it's parsed as a JOSN string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having this issue because `variations` already has the parsed value, [as said in the doc](https://api.jquery.com/data/) :

> When a string starts with '{' or '[', then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse it

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
 let variations = $( "span" ).data( "variations" );

 $( variations ).each( function ( index, variation ) {
  console.log( variation );
 } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-variations='["\ud83d\udc36","\ud83d\udc31"]'></span>
```

Comment: Note that this jQuery behaviour is different to the *native* [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

Comment: Assuming it's valid JSON. This will return a string: `data-data="{'test':1}"`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery notices that the value of the `data-` attribute is valid JSON, so you get a parsed object from the `.data("variations")` call. There's no need to parse it yourself.

Comment: That behavior is surprising, perhaps, but it's what's happening in this case.

Comment: <...>  attribute is _valid_ JSON <...>